# Two definitions of intersection multiplicity:

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Say we have two affine plane curves that pass through $P=(0,0)$, namely $X=Z(f), Y=Z(g)$. In the begging of the book "Intersection theory" by Fulton he defines the intersection multiplicity of $X,Y$ at $P$ as: 
$dim_k\mathcal O_P$ where $\mathcal O$ is the structure sheaf of the (scheme-theoretic) intersection $X\cap Y$.

However, In chapter I, section 5 of Hartshorn's "Algebraic Geometry" he defines the the intersection multiplicity as $length \mathcal O_P$ over $k[x,y]_P$, the localized coordinate ring of $\mathbb A^2$.

Why are these definitions equivalent? When we define more general intersection multiplicities, such as when $M$ is a good graded module over a good graded ring $S$, then also Hartshorne defines the multiplicity of $M$ at some minimal prime of $Ann(M)$ as the length of $M_P$ over $S_P$. Can this definition be reformulated in terms of dimension? 
What are the essential differences in these definitions?

Comment: Any Artin local ring of the form $\mathcal{O}_P$ can be filtered by $K=\mathcal{O}_P/\mathfrak{m}$. So, length of $\mathcal{O}_P\cdot [K:k]=\dim_k\mathcal{O}_P$. In your case, $k=K$, so the two numbers are the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Definition of intersection multiplicity in Hartshorne VS Fulton for plane curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961889/definition-of-intersection-multiplicity-in-hartshorne-vs-fulton-for-plane-curves)